# Substring in Angularjs using filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having the following array that i want to manipulate in DOM using Angularjs with some filters

```
$scope.urls = [{
    path: 'http://a.com/index'        
    }, {
     path: 'http://a.com/home'        
    }, {
    path: 'http://a.com/etc'        
    }, {
    path: 'http://a.com/all'        
   }];
```

I had tried to substring the path using filters but it is not working.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yPE6j/)

Any help is great.

Comment: Do you want to get output: index, home, etc, all ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
  <h1>Only path without domain name:</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="url in urls | myCustomFilter">{{url.path}}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.urls = [{
        path: 'http://a.com/index'        
    }, {
         path: 'http://a.com/home'        
    }, {
        path: 'http://a.com/etc'        
    }, {
        path: 'http://a.com/all'        
    }];

    $scope.otherCondition = true;
});
fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];

 fessmodule.filter('myCustomFilter', function() {
   return function( urls) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(urls, function(url) {
        filtered.push( {path:url.path.substring("http://a.com".length, url.path.length)});
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/845/)**</kbd>

*As a side note:*

Try to write filters out of controller.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS v 1.4.5 supports a standard "limitTo" filter for arrays(including string) with parameters length and offset:

```
<div ng-controller = "SampleController"> 
  <h1>Result of substring equivalent filter:</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="url in urls">{{url.path | limitTo:5:12}}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Note**: This solution fails in case of dynamic domain length("http://a.com" static length of 12).

**Note 2**: Increase length to the maximum resulting length of path(Max is "index" having length of 5).

[Overview of all filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) supported by AngularJS out of the box.