# Retrieve last numbers from URL in JSON - angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs app that loads in data from this JSON file:

http://www.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/leagueTable?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teamsList">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>

        <td><a href="#/teams/{{team._links.team.href}}">
              {{team.teamName}}
              </a></td>
        <td>{{team.playedGames}}</td>
        <td>{{team.points}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goals}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goalsAgainst}}</td>
        <td>{{team.goalDifference}}</td>
      </tr>
```

However in this part of the code: `<td><a href="#/teams/{{team._links.team.href}}">` which loads in  URL eg. http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/61 I want to retrieve the last numbers at the end, they could be longer than 2 or less, instead of the whole URL. So anything after that last /, is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to write a filter like this one: [Substring in Angularjs using filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20394181/584846)

If it's always two digits, you could get away with this:

```
<a href="#/teams/{{team._links.team.href|limitTo:-2}}">
```

Comment: thanks, the only snag is that it could be 1, 2 or 3 digits long. Any idea to make sure it will always capture them?

Comment: Looks like you will have to either write a filter function or process `teamsList` into a new list in your controller (extracting the team id).